# How to lock aperture using Reverse ring with Canon 600D?

Tags: lens, canon, aperture, reversed-lens

Is there anyone using reverse ring and know how to lock the aperture.

I tried doing the techniques provided on youtube. First connecting the lens on original positions then lock the aperture by pressing the AE lock button on the camera. after that reverse the lens.

But this method is not locking the aperture.

Help if anyone know how to lock in reverse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the aperture for a Canon EOS lens to a position other than the widest aperture is relatively simple:

- With the EOS camera powered on and the lens mounted select the aperture you wish in either **Manual (M)** or **Aperture Priority (Av)** exposure mode.
- Press the *Depth of Field Preview* button and continue to hold it down. Not all Canon EOS models include a *DoF Preview* button, but some will allow you to custom map another button to that function.
- Press the lens release button and remove the lens before releasing the *DoF Preview* button.

The aperture will remain in that position until it is reconnected to a powered up EOS camera.

Answer (score 2):

The only method I am aware of is using an adapter that connects the camera mount and the lens mount and transfers their electrical signals.

[One of these adapters](https://www.novoflex.com/en/products/macro-accessories/reverse-adapter-eos-retro/) is made by Novoflex, but I assume there are others.

Comment: yes but how to lock the aperture?

Comment: The ring provides all control functions from the camera, so you can lock it in there.