# What are the options for an ultra-wide angle rectilinear lens adapted for Sony Full Frame?

Tags: nikon, equipment-recommendation, pentax, ultra-wide, sony-alpha

I shoot with the Sony Alpha line predominately and currently have a 24mm Quantary Aspherical that I use on it but want to get something wider, ultra-wide. I'm not sure what to get though.

I have adapters for Nikon F and Pentax K but could always buy another adapter if really need to.

I'm trying to find a good lens wider than 24, still rectilinear lines, and with an aperture ring. Maybe there's a lens from Nikon film days I haven't been able to find yet? Any recommendations would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultra-wide lenses typically didn't exist in film days. Anything below 24mm is very hard to find. You *might* be able to grab an 18mm (like, say, the Olympus OM 18/3.5), but understand these were super-exotic at the time, and are liable to go for high prices.  You'd probably be better off saving up for the 16-35, getting the 28/2 with the 21mm wide converter, or maybe looking at the Samyang 14mm f/2.8.

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000)

Comment: Hmm Ken Rockwell's reviews of that Samyang leaves a pretty low impression. The 16-35 being substantially more expensive from what I'm seeing, over $1,000... is there a Manual version I might find for less? Or do you think I could make use of Nikon 18mm/3.5 which appears to be around $400?

Comment: Keep in mind that Ken Rockwell a) does not actually use all of the lenses he "reviews" and b) compares his own site to *The Onion*

Comment: @mattdm so the Samyang 14mm is a good lens?

Comment: For the money, it is an *amazing* lens.

Comment: @Ryan, be aware there are two versions of the Samyang 14/2.8. [The second version (UMC)](http://www.lenstip.com/239.1-Lens_review-Samyang_14_mm_f_2.8_ED_AS_IF_UMC__Introduction.html) corrected for a lot of the issues in the first version.

Answer (score 4):

## Nikkor Ultra-Wide Lenses

[Nikon used to make, and still makes, several non-distorting manual-focus prime ultra-wide lenses.](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/index.htm) Some are discontinued whilst others are still available for sale new to date. Their focal lengths are: 13mm, 15mm, 18mm, and 20mm. Personally I'd buy a 13mm just because it looks and feels awesome.

### The [13mm f5.6](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/13mm.htm)

Pictured below in its AI-S version, this lens is scarcely available for purchase used online. Expect it to be expensive.

[image: Nikkor 13mm f5.6 AI-S] 
<sup>*[Nikkor 13mm f/5.6 Ultra/Super Wideangle lens](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/13mm_Nikkor-Manual/index.htm)*, Fair Use, MIR</sup>

### The [15mm f5.6](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/late70nikkor/ultrawides/15mm.htm)

Pictured below in its AI-S version, this lens is scarcely available for purchase used online. Expect it to be expensive.

[image: 15mm f5.6 AI-S 1978] 
 
<sup>*[15mm f5.6 1978](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/late70nikkor/ultrawides/15mm.htm)*, Fair Use, MIR</sup>

### The [15mm f3.5](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/15mm.htm)

Pictured below in its AI-S version, this lens is sometimes available for purchase used online. Expect it to be expensive.

[image: 15mm f3.5 AI-S] 
 
<sup>*[15mmAISf35b.JPG](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/15mm.htm)*, Fair Use, MIR</sup>

### The [18mm f3.5](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/18mm.htm)

Pictured below in its AI-S version, this lens is sometimes available for purchase used online.

[image: 18mm f3.5 AI-S] 
 
<sup>*[Manual Focus Nikkor 18mm f/3.5 wideangle lens](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/18mm.htm)*, Fair Use, MIR</sup>

### The [20mm f2.8](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/ultrawides/20mm.htm)

Pictured below in its AI-S version, Nikon still makes and sells new 20mm f2.8 AI-S. B&H sells them for USD619.00 as of February 2016.

[image: 18mm f3.5 AI-S] 
 
<sup>*[Nikon NIKKOR 20mm f/2.8 Lens](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/36905-GREY/Nikon_1415_Super_Wide_Angle_20mm.html)*, Fair Use, B&H</sup>

### The [20mm f3.5](https://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/late70nikkor/ultrawides/20mma.htm)

Pictured below in both its AI and AI-S version, this lens is sometimes available for purchase used online.

[image: 18mm f3.5 AI-S] 
 
<sup>*[Nikon NIKKOR 20mm f/2.8 Lens](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/36905-GREY/Nikon_1415_Super_Wide_Angle_20mm.html)*, Fair Use, MIR</sup>

Comment: Don't forget the 20mm/f3.5 - easier to find, and quite fine.

Comment: @rackandboneman Done. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

I have a **Sigma 12-24 f3.5-5.6 EX DG HSM** for my Nikon D610. It is a full-frame rectilinear lens. There is also a "II" version of this lens. It used to be the widest rectilinear lens for full-frame (until that Canon 11mm zoom). 12mm rectilinear on full-frame is extremely wide.

I can use it, **with an adapter that can control the aperture manually**, with my Sony APSC e-mount too. I suppose it can be used with a Sony full-frame ALPHA too, with the appropriate adapter.

Comment: Sigma also makes the lens in the Sony E mount. Only drawback is price. It's about $1000.

Comment: @inkista Can you link me to the lens? I see variants of it in A-mount.

Comment: @unsignedzero Whoops. You're right. I misread. A-mount only.

Answer (score 1):

Older Nikon lens do exist, such as the 14-24/2.8, 20-35/2.8, 16-35/4 or related but wide lens aren't that common back in the day.

If you want to get a new one you might consider the Tamron 15-30/2.8. It's a new, cheaper alternative to modern ultrawide zooms. I believe they might also have a A-mount so you would be set there.

I presume when you say "Sony Alpha" you mean A-mount and not the E-mount.

Comment: E-mount Sony A7. I'm not familiar with any Sony A-mount cameras that are full frame. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There's also the fairly recent Canon EF 11-24mm f/4 L. It is an incredible lens. It is also about $3K USD.

[image]

Comment: ...and you can't control the aperture on the lens unless you have a $400 adapter ring.

Comment: Impressive. Is this your rig or just an image you found? Not to mention @inkista point about the adapter ring for aperture, but I would also be concerned about the weight not having a tripod collar built in.

Comment: Or a Canon body with which to set it and leave it at any of the available settings. http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/54344/15871

Comment: @Ryan Not mine. But I have seen one. It's not that big nor heavy that I would worry about too much stress on the mount. It weighs less than 2.5 lbs and at max extension is less than 6" in front of the flange. That's about the same as the old EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L (which is a little lighter but extends further).

Answer (score 0):

Also: The (in)famous plastic fantastic. Cosina 19-35mm f/3.5-4.5, often sold as a Vivitar Series 1 but also by other brands (Tokina and Tamron lenses with same spec exist, not sure if they are the same optical design). Not perfect, also far from useless, and can often be found for very reasonable prices at camera shows etc. Made in a variety of mounts. Inspect carefully for fungus - it is practically impossible to disassemble and clean the rear group.

Also: Tokina 20-35mm f/2.8 AT-X pro.

Also: Not technically film era lenses, the various Rokinon/Samyang/... 12mm and 14mm full frames and their rebrands and derivatives that are common in various SLR mounts. Watch for decentering issues!

---

Something to be aware of when adapting ultrawides, even more with ultrawide zooms: Even small flange focal distance errors in the adapters *can cause utter havoc w/rt field curvature*. Having an universal adapter with adjustable length and some known good digital calipers handy, probably also some shimming stock (eg thin sheet metal as used in old flatscreen monitors for shielding, kapton tape, circuit board stock), probably also tinsnips, drills, a calculator, is recommendable when experimenting with adapting ultrawides.