# Why is my reversal ring not working with the lens's aperture?

Tags: macro, reverse-mount, reversed-lens

Recently I bought a reversal ring for my Canon 700D, to take macro photography. I reversed an 18-55mm kit lens. When I tried to take photos, the aperture went to f00. What can I do to set the aperture?

Comment: Have you set the exposure mode dial to "Manual?"

Comment: Related: [How to lock aperture using Reverse ring with Canon 600D?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54338/how-to-lock-aperture-using-reverse-ring-with-canon-600d/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no electronic connection between the lens and the body. Except if you have bought the [macro adapter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1050997-REG/vello_rm_cef_macrofier_reverse_mount_adapter.html).

If you want to control the aperture, you have two options:

1. Buy an adapter that provides the communication between the body and the lens.
2. Use an old (any brand) lens with a manual aperture setting. The old auto aperture used a mechanical contact (pushpin for M42 mount, lever for F-mount) to control the aperture from the body. The automatic ones without A/M switch will always be wide open. Some lenses can be set to "manual" mode and the aperture can be controlled directly. Some lenses are fully manual and aperture is controlled directly.
3. [Cheat the lens to "remember" the last aperture setting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54338/how-to-lock-aperture-using-reverse-ring-with-canon-600d/), as @Michal Clark noted.

In both cases you should be able to shoot in A/S/M modes. For P and auto I'm not sure.

Options sorted by price: 3 - 2 - 1.
Options sorted by user comfort: 1 - 2 - 3.

Comment: There is a [third option](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/54338/how-to-lock-aperture-using-reverse-ring-with-canon-600d/) to control the aperture.

Comment: @MichaelClark true, but I think it is possible to control the apperture this way. But is it useful?

Comment: It's useful if you want to shoot with the lens stopped down when it is reversed. It's certainly more useful than not being able to control the aperture at all when using a reversing ring.

Comment: If you have old manual lens, or you can buy one for reasonably low price, it is much easier to turn the ring. I am using old Porst and Reuvenon lenses I bought for old Petri SLR earlier. If you want to change the apperture of EF lens, you have to re-attach it to the body and change the setting.

Comment: A lot of macro work is done at a constant aperture. In which case it is a rather elegant solution.

Comment: Not all old manual lenses are as easy to control as the ones you use. Nikon F lenses, for instance, are spring loaded and stop down to minimum aperture when there is nothing pushing against the aperture lever. Since it needs to be pushed a different distance for each setting, every time one changes the aperture ring one would also need to push the lever against the spring and retape it.

Comment: If you know what apperture to set. Yes, there are lenses with "automatic apperture" for M42 mount there is a pin to be pushed by the body; F-mount use a lever. Porst No.771515 35mm/1:2.8 has the A/M switch that disables the push-pin control. Auto revuenon MC No.500157 doesn't have this switch and I have to push the pin somehow. On the other hand; Mayer optik Orestor 135mm/2.8 doesn't have any automated option at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56102/discussion-between-crowley-and-michael-clark).

Answer (score 0):

You can do nothing as reverse ring do not provide any electrical contacts/connection from lens to the body. You can still shoot but you should get it mind the aperture you use for those shoots.

Also is good to make the aperture smaller than fully opened to increase depth of field in the macro photography